# What can I use to open a floating point tiff?

Tags: gimp

On [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5414586/how-do-i-save-a-mode-f-image-python-pil) thread I saw that GIMP is not displaying this tiff image right. Is there another program I can use to open it?

Answer (score 3):

You need to report this issue to the gimp developers and provide sample files for them to work with, you will find their bug tracker here:

http://www.gimp.org/bugs/howtos/bugzilla.html

Then attempt to use imagemagick to transform the tiff into a png, if that works then you know that libtiff is probably ok. If it doesn't work in  imagemagick then try some other tools, like the eye-of-gnome.

Make sure that once you've tested all these and found them in error, you should report the bug to the libtiff developers:

http://www.libtiff.org/bugs.html